# Extract MSG attachments from a PST archive

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I have a PST (Outlook archive) file containing all my messages after recovering them using Kernel Outlook Repair, but the recovery program has saved all the actual emails as as .msg attachments on each message in the PST.

Is there any way to extract all the attachments from a PST archive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a freeware program from NirSoft that might help: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/outlook_attachment.html

OutlookAttachView scans all messages stored in your Outlook, and displays the list of all attached files that it finds. You can easily select one or more attachments and save all of them into the desired folder, as well as you can delete unwanted large attachments that take too much disk space in your mailbox. You can also save the list of attachments into xml/html/text/csv file.

Comment: While this may solve the problem, link only answers aren't a good fit for this site. Perhaps you could expand on why it may work

Comment: From the link that I posted: _OutlookAttachView scans all messages stored in your Outlook, and displays the list of all attached files that it finds. You can easily select one or more attachments and save all of them into the desired folder, as well as you can delete unwanted large attachments that take too much disk space in your mailbox. You can also save the list of attachments into xml/html/text/csv file._

Comment: You can delete your comment now. If there's a suggestion to improve your answer, you can edit your answer rather than leaving a comment.

Comment: I ended up using this in the end. Worked pretty well, despite having ~5k messages to parse through!

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative. There is also a **free** [Save Attachments](https://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookAttachmentsSave/) utility that can be utilized for that. Just specify *.msg as an "Include attachments" option and destination folder on your disk.

One more useful utility here is the [Import Messages from MSG Files](https://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookMessagesImportMSG/) (also free) that can be utilized to load messages back to Outlook.

Please note: I recommend these utilities because I'm one of the developers.